# NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load

Tags: android, ajax, django, cordova

Server side is Django/python.

Client environment is cordova/android.
 This request fails :

```
    $.ajax({
    url: myAddress,
    type: 'POST',
    data: mydata,
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    async: false,
    success: function () { mycode},
    error: function (xhr) { mycode}        }
});
```

When myAddress is 192.168.1.11 it works perfectly.

When myAddress is dev.mysite.com i get the error:

**NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load dev.mysite.com/../..**

However, i can connect to the same django web server with chrome on the mobile device.

config.xml contains : **access origin="*"**

Do you have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: on the django/python web server i add the module django-cors-header to authorize cors request. But nothing change.

Comment: I can connect to the web server by the local address(192.168.1.13) and the IP address (86.XX.YYY) but not with the domain name.

Comment: I remove and reinstall the cordova plugin whitelist. But nothing change

Comment: apparently, the problem is independant of cordova. I have similar error on the same request in an HTML/javascript page. The error is :                         Error {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"

Comment: i add in index.html                 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' dev.mysiste.com  data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">  But it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

The js code is good.
The CSP code is good.

My problem came from my misunderstanding of http redirection at the DNS level.

Thank you for you attention

Comment: We're suddenly running into the same problem. How did you solve this?